# Unlock/login Windows 7 with keyboard only

Tags: windows-7, login-screen, lock-screen, winlogon.exe

The Windows 7 login/lock screen sucks because you need to click first at the user icon and then enter the password. This not only inconvniently requires both Mouse and keyboard, I often have trouble starting up my laptop very dimmed and I can't see the mouse pointer.
I could (so far) not even find a key combination which always works (e.g., tab, tab, password or so).

I tried already "Interactive logon: No not display last username" policy and "do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL". But this seems to work only for the login but not the lock screen and furthermore, it's just plain more work ($username$password).

Is there a way to improve the situation?

Comment: Do away with the lock screen and put a password on a screensaver, then you only need a keyboard.

Comment: It sounds multiple users log into this computer.  Is that the case?

Comment: Does pressing `tab` highlight the user accounts in turn?

Comment: screensaver is of course NO solution (in particular, computer is locked whenever I wake it up from standby). No, pressing TAB does not highlight accounts. Yes, multiple accounts. In particular, one "pseudo account" (entry) for the fingerprint reader ...

Answer (score 1):

Use Tab. You will notice that the default selected item is the shutdown button. Use Tab and Shift+Tab, and you will see the Shutdown and other buttons being highlighted (though it is very hard to see).

Although you can see the Shutdown buttons being highlighted, you cannot see the user-name buttons being highlighted, so you have to count. As soon as you Tab off of the Shutdown/Menu (2 tabs), you are on the first user box. 3 Tabs takes you to the second user box, and so on.